# Consulta SQL não está agrupando

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Sou novato em SQL e estou tentando agrupar os dados conforme query abaixo, porém, não está agrupando.
O correto era para sair, por exemplo

```
select
    left(P.ProjDesc,6),
    COUNT(P.ProjID)
from Projetos P
where P.ProjStatus <> 9 
group by p.ProjDesc
```

Comment: Seja mais específico em relação ao objetivo da query, oque você quer realmente retornar ?

Comment: Bem, era para retornar da seguinte maneira

Descricao      Quantidade de Projetos
Rafael                       50 
Teles                         20

, porém, está vindo assim
Rafael   1
Rafael   1
Rafael   1
Rafael   1
Teles     1
Teles     1
Teles     1
Teles     1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renan,

Pelo que entendi, você deseja agrupar a partir do LEFT. Utilize a query abaixo.

```
select 
     left(P.ProjDesc,6), 
     COUNT(P.ProjID) 
from 
     Projetos P 
where 
     P.ProjStatus <> 9 
group by 
     left(P.ProjDesc,6)
```

Neste caso, você agrupará pela mesma coluna que selecionou.

Abraço,

Comment: Ah . Show de Bola Jean. Esqueci desse detalhe. Obrigadão cara. Abraços